# Remove questions that are old and not concluded?

Tags: discussion

I just browse through questions on Stack Overflow and occasionally stumble upon questions that haven't been answered, very old and have mostly lost their importance by now.

Should there be a provision to remove such questions from Stack Overflow? Maybe a queue where we can push such questions for administrators to review and decide?

Why I am saying remove instead of closed is because these questions haven't been answered nor concluded in any way. So when a user will search for problems, the user will come across these as false positives.

E.g., *[I can't import Spring guide and deploy it correctly. I get a 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835952/i-cant-import-spring-guide-and-deploy-it-correctly-i-get-a-404-error)*

Comment: Is that question useful? If no, cast a down vote and it will roomba in the weekend.

Comment: If you think a question provides no value at all to the site, you can always decide to cast a downvote, which will trigger the roomba in several days. For questions like the one you linked (spelling mistakes all over, weird and possibly dated instructions like _Click next, next, next_), I think a downvote is appropriate.

Comment: Cool sounds good let's follow this approach then. Can you post this as an answer. So others know what approach to take :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think a question is no longer useful, downvote it. Likewise if you think it's useful upvote it.

Voting allows the system to rate the question and delete it earlier.

For this specific question if you downvote it [a process known as the roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) will delete it within a few days.

Answer (score 11):

> Should there be a provision to remove such questions from Stack Overflow?

There already is such a provision. It is called [The Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). It deletes questions that are closed and/or are 30 days old and/or are 365 days old (depending on score and number of comments).

> Maybe a queue where we can push such questions for administrators to review and decide?

Let's not add yet another queue and put the burden on the few users that like to sift through that junkyard. You do realize you are an administrator as well, right? Casting downvotes and close votes on questions that are unclear and not useful is a very powerful curation technique. The privilege to casting downvotes comes at 125 reputation points. There are more than enough users that can cast downvotes and if they all did the roomba would do its work.

> Why I am saying remove instead of closed is because these questions haven't been answered nor concluded in any way. So when a user will search for problems will come across these as false positives.

Exactly! Which we, that is you and me and the rest of the users that form this community, should take their responsibility and vote and flag early and often. Expecting the 'administrators' (still not sure who those are) to clean up the posts (growing by eight thousand each day) is not going to cut it. We need that large pool of users that are able to vote to use their privilege. Only that will lead to a situation that searching for a problem will result in fewer false positives.

Please become part of the solution; you're all invited.

Comment: But that requires the right frame of mind. As long as it is *"I don't want to hurt users by downvoting their posts; I am not a sadist"* it will not change. The web site itself ought to further the right frame of mind: *"I want a high-quality site. I will support that by downvoting, if necessary"*.

Comment: Indeed. But if you don't have that frame of mind you can always go to [r/ProgrammerHumor](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/bz0odb/new_template_new_memes_bashing_on_stack/). There is a site for everyone.

Comment: How about, *I don’t want to hurt users and waste their time by* not *downvoting low-quality and/or uninteresting posts*? This is what the site should really be encouraging.